Squirt chain lube friction
I have been using squirt chain lube for the past year ~ 5000 miles and the chain wear is still less than 0.5% and my riding style is pretty typical for me.
I'm wondering, is there a site that documents different chain lubes and how they compare to one another (friction, chain durability, wet/dry)?
While this appears to last longer than Boeshield T9, it is dirtier, and I have only about 5000 mi of data on it whereas I have about 15000 mi of data on Boeshield T9.
I am using the same chain in both cases KMC X10-SL.

Not that I know of.   Too many variables to account for, I suspect.   My chain wear rate doubles in winter, for example.

Here are the key charts from an article on Velo from 2013 on how long lubrication lasted and friction (they called it efficiency) for different chain lubricants - wet and dry.
They do not indicate which lube will make your chain go more miles. I think the information given does point to paraffin wax as a likely winner.
How long the lubrication lasted

Longevity results
We tested eight of the lubes for longevity, simulating a single dirty, wet ride and testing efficiency before and after. Each of the eight was chosen as a representative of a certain lube type. For the most part, four of the eight, representing greases, wax-based drip lubes, regular oils, and biodegradeable oils, were all very similar, losing about 2 watts over the hour-long test.



Efficiency results
The fastest bike lube isn’t designed for your bike at all. In every measure, the most efficient chain lubricant is simple paraffin wax, sold in solid blocks at any hardware store. In the efficiency test it was faster than the best bike lube by 0.24 watts and the
worst by 3.05 watts under ideal conditions. Following an hour covered in dirt, sand, and water, the paraffin was nearly 6 watts faster than the worst performing lube.



Thanks, another data point.  That helps, I left one metric out, environment impact.  I switched from T9 to Squirt as Squirt is supposed to be non toxic and safe for the environment.  But yes, I mainly wanted to see metrics on it, not a recommendation one way or the other.

Is Park Tools CL-I among the worst in the last graph ind the second best in the first one? Am I reading those charts correctly?

That's what the charts say. Higher friction but it stays on the chain almost like wax.

The absolute reference on the topic was Zero Friction Cycling: https://zerofrictioncycling.com.au/ (it doesn't distinguish wet/dry though).
I use the past tense, as at the time of writing, no new content seems to have been added for about 1.5 years. The site was mostly ran by one person, and these kind of site tend to be short-lived, but it contains a lot of useful information.
Note also that "link-only answer" are off-topic here, as the goal of this site is too have a self-contained database of Q&A, and Stack Exchange has no control on what's happening when you leave their site.

Adam at ZFC is still working on lubes, but new material now comes mostly to YouTube. He does claim he updates the charts on the web page, though, even if he doesn’t publish written test reports. I haven’t followed him close enough to know for sure, though. Per ZFC, Boeshield and Squirt are not too far from each other with T9 being better in no contamination block and squirt in dry contamination block, after which they wear about the same.
